# Cobertura showing 0% coverage

Tags: netbeans, junit, cobertura

I'm using Cobertura 1.9.3 with NetBeans 6.8, Ant 1.7.1 and JDK 1.6.0_21 running with -WAR, and EJB, JUnit 4 tests.

When I change the line `pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}" /` to `pathelement location="${build.test.classes.dir}" /`, there is some coverage (albeit in the wrong classes, it shouldn't be in the testclass, just to show that the environment and .jar locations are set correctly) shown in the html reports.

However, when I change it back to `pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}" /`, I always get 0% coverage.

fwiw, when the instrumentation folders do contain instrumented classes in `${build.instrumented.dir}` (these classes are slightly larger than the ones in the `${build.classes.dir}` location). And yes, I've retried after deleting `cobertura.ser` from the previous run.

Could I please have a clue on what's wrong?

Cheers,

Snippet of `build.xml` in a `-ejb` folder.

```
           <property environment="env"/>
           <path id="cobertura.class.path">
               <fileset dir="${build.dir}/../../lib">
                   <include name="**/*.jar"/>
               </fileset>
           </path>
           <taskdef classpathref="cobertura.class.path" resource="tasks.properties"/>

           <target name="-pre-compile-test">
               <delete dir="${build.instrumented.dir}" />
               <delete dir="${build.report.cobertura.dir}" />
               <mkdir dir="${build.instrumented.dir}" />
               <mkdir dir="${build.report.cobertura.dir}" />
               <cobertura-instrument todir="${build.instrumented.dir}" classpathref="cobertura.class.path">
                   <ignore regex="org.apache.log4j.*" />
                   <includeClasses regex=".*" />
                   <excludeClasses regex=".*\.Test.*" />
                   <excludeClasses regex=".*\.TestSuite.*" />

                   <instrumentationClasspath>
                       <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}" />
                   </instrumentationClasspath>
               </cobertura-instrument>
           </target>

           <target name="-post-test-run">
               <cobertura-report format="html" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.report.cobertura.dir}"/>
               <cobertura-report format="xml" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.report.cobertura.dir}"/>
           </target>
```

===

Edit: I also have the following set up:

```
        ...
        build.test.classes.dir=${build.dir}/test/classes
        build.test.results.dir=${build.dir}/test/results
        build.instrumented.dir=${build.dir}/instrumented
        build.report.dir=${build.dir}/report
        build.report.cobertura.dir=${build.report.dir}/cobertura
        ...
        javac.classpath=\
        ${libs.GlassFish_v3.classpath}:\
        ${file.reference.mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar}
        ...
        javac.test.classpath=\
        ${javac.classpath}:\
        ${file.reference.mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar}:\
        ${libs.Libraries_Needed_For_JUnit.classpath}:\
        ${build.instrumented.dir}:\
        ${build.classes.dir}:\
        ${libs.junit_4.classpath}
        ...
        run.test.classpath=\
        ${javac.test.classpath}:\
        ${file.reference.mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar}:\
        ${libs.Cobertura.classpath}:\
        ${libs.Libraries_Needed_For_JUnit.classpath}:\
        ${libs.junit_4.classpath}:\
        ${build.test.classes.dir}
        ...
        src.dir=${source.root}/java
        test.src.dir=test
```

Comment: I'm also on a version control system so I have the Use Dedicated Folder for sharing libraries option checked in NetBeans, as well as the Copy Server JAR Files to Libraries Folder option. I've had previous issues in which I failed to import relevant libraries but this doesn't seem like a library issue...

Comment: See http://techo-ecco.com/blog/testng-with-cobertura/ on how to configure it correctly

Answer (score 0):

The only case when you get 0% coverage is

- When you have not set your classpath correctly, your tests are
  running against non instrumented code, or,
- Your .ser (metadata) file is stale, whenever you build/rebuild your code, you should delete the existing metadata file and instrument again.

See here for a good example on classpath https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/wiki/Ant-Task-Reference

Also, it's a good idea to keep instrumented classes in a separate folder, as well as specify a different folder for test classes.